# Applying for EEA Family Permit strictly 3 months in advance?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, entry-permit

Is it allowed to apply for EEA Family Permit for a short sightseeing trip earlier than 3 months before travel or is there the same 3-months-rule in place like for Standard UK visa?

The reason I'm asking is that I'll be abroad in the middle of these three months with probably not enough time to get my permit before or after this other trip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply for an EEA family permit up to six months before your planned travel.  From the UK's [eligibility page](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility):

> The EEA citizen you’re joining must either:
>
> - be in the UK already
> - be travelling with you to the UK within 6 months of the date of your application

(This statement of the requirement isn't quite correct, though, because it is also acceptable for the EEA citizen you're joining to be outside the UK when you apply, but traveling to the UK before you do.)

Comment: Thank you! So now it's just to wait for an appointment to become available! :)